# Login page doesn't appear

Tags: 20.04, gnome, login-screen

Whenever I boot my laptop, my Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't show login page and just shows a cursor in a black screen.

I find out by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, the login page appears.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the archwiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GDM

> GDM does not start until switching TTY and back
>
> If, after booting, the screen stays black and GDM does not start until
> changing to another TTY and then back to TTY1, it may be because GDM
> is being attempted to run before GPU driver is loaded.
>
> One possible solution is adding your GPU driver module to be built
> into initial ramdisk with mkinitcpio, by adding the module name into
> `MODULES` entry in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`. Make sure that initcpio files
> get generated afterwards.
>
> An alternative walkaround is to add delay to GDM service file.
>
> ```
> # systemctl edit gdm
>
> [Service]  
> ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 1
> ```

try to run the below command to edit the gdm file

```
sudo systemctl edit gdm
```

put above two lines below the last lines of the opened file. If delay of 1 sec is not working try to increase the delay.

save and restart the gdm with below command

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm
```