# TTY 1 opens everytime I want to login on ubuntu 21.10 with Gnome 40

Tags: command-line, gnome, login, tty, 21.10

Recently a weird thing is happening, every time I try to login into my user account, ubuntu opens something similar to a TTY, but it is not exactly a TTY.

So what exactly happens is, I boot up my system, the login screen prompts and I click on the user name I want to login to. Once I click on the username it opens a login prompt but instead of opening a GUI prompt, it opens a TTY-like CLI prompt.

The prompt looks like-

```
Ubuntu 21.10 Linux console

Linux login:
```

After I login into it, I get just a normal TTY interface (I can only type commands).

Some important information:-

- I am on ubuntu 21.10 Impish with Gnome 40.
- Sometimes it straightaway boots into that TTY-like interface.
- I am using [orchis](https://github.com/vinceliuice/Orchis-theme) as a shell theme and application theme.
- I have changed the GDM background image to a custom wallpaper using [this script from GitHub](https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/ubuntu-gdm-set-background)
- **I could temporarily fix this issue by going to TTY2 and then again TTY1.**

When I go to TTY2 and then switch to TTY1 the Login prompt is fine as usual.

Here are the contents of `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

```bsh
$ cat custom.conf


# GDM configuration storage
#
# See /usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas for a list of available options.

[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
#WaylandEnable=false

# Enabling automatic login
#  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
#  AutomaticLogin = user1

# Enabling timed login
#  TimedLoginEnable = true
#  TimedLogin = user1
#  TimedLoginDelay = 10

AutomaticLoginEnable=False
AutomaticLogin=user_name

[security]

[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
# More verbose logs
# Additionally lets the X server dump core if it crashes
#Enable=true
```

Here is the list of gnome-extensions installed:

```
~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions$ ls -c

just-perfection-desktop@just-perfection
arcmenu@arcmenu.com
cpufreq@konkor
blur-my-shell@aunetx
dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
caffeine@patapon.info
```

If you want any other information then please feel free to ask me in the comments.

#### Edit

I tried using lightdm as the display manager but that also didn't worked.

Comment: Sounds like your Xorg server is crashing when you try to log in.  Look at the latest file in `/var/log/X*` (or possibly the second latest) and see if there are interesting errors at the end.

Comment: Any line with EE on the left is interesting.

Comment: Is the gkr-pam line the last line in the file?  Check the last several files (sort with `ls -ltr /var/log/X*`) and make sure you are looking at the log file from the crash, not the current one after it restarted.

Comment: Your problem is with *"I have changed the GDM background image to a custom wallpaper using this script from GitHub"*. Undo this.

Comment: @heynnema Did it, no change...

Comment: @someone can you give it a try with delay of 5sec https://askubuntu.com/q/1380436/739431

Comment: `[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 5` two lines

Comment: `sudo systemctl edit gdm` and after edits, is the above MSG came??

Comment: The file opened with `nano` text editor.

Comment: Ok I am doing it on my system too let's see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132448/discussion-between-someone-and-unknown).

Comment: @heynnema It wasn't me!

Comment: @someone Then I apologize.