# Ubuntu Studio 22.04 Log-in screens pops up and then disappers

Tags: login, 22.04, gdm

I have somewhat similar problem to [Login page doesn't appear](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380436/login-page-doesnt-appear)

In my case sometimes, though not always, I can see the log-on-screen pop up for maybe 1 second and then I get a black screen with a mouse cursor. No keystroke seems to do anything. All I can do is to switch to a console and shut down the machine.

It mostly happens if I don't press any key during boot-up and just wait for the times to run down.

The command described in the other Thread "sudo systemctl restart gdm" comes back with an error message. I also tried the extra lines in the startup-script, with a delay of 3 seconds. No avail.

Here is the output of "journalctl -xeu gdm.service"

```
Okt 22 17:09:30 marina-latitudee6440 systemd[1]: gdm.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
```

Okt 22 17:09:30 marina-latitudee6440 systemd[1]: gdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit gdm.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Okt 22 17:09:30 marina-latitudee6440 systemd[1]: Failed to start GNOME Display Manager.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit gdm.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit gdm.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4344 and the job result is failed.
Okt 22 17:09:30 marina-latitudee6440 systemd[1]: gdm.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.

Comment: Ubuntustudio 22.04 uses `sddm` by default, not `gdm`. Did you install `gdm` after OS-installation?

Comment: No, I didn’t. Everything is stock in this regard. I‘m not a programmer but a experienced user. I‘m not so deep in these specific details.

Comment: I cannot help you much with your issue, but one thing is sure: it does not make much sense to run `sudo systemctl restart gdm` if you don't use `gdm` and it's not installed at all. Maybe it helps if you replace `gdm` with `sddm` in the command.

Comment: I can see that now. I was sort of „barking up the wrong tree“. But after you hinted me that it‘s actually sddm I found this well known bug, that’s still unsolved, as it seems: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SDDM#Blank_screen_with_cursor,_but_no_greeter_shows. There is a workaround though, described here: https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues/1179#issuecomment-538750767

Comment: The workaround is a bit of a nuisance, but it works for me - just tested it.